# Magento2 QTY is always decimal, is this default? Can it be set non decimal?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, qty

My `QTY` is always in decimal for all products I import, is the decimal qty actually magento2's default?

I've set the column on my import, but it seems I always get the decimal regardless. How do I set this properly?

See a lot about, `is_qty_decimal`, doesn't really appear to do anything of course.

Comment: Is the question about the product entity attribute `quantity_and_stock_status` ? Did you check the `eav_attribute` table for the type of the attribute?

Comment: Please answer anything you can inform us on, because lord knows no good information exists on this.  Is the quantity really a decimal throughout the cart?  Is that the default?  What does that property actually mean?